# Using 3d array as key for map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Let's say I have a map using a 3d array of ints as a key, and another int as the value:

```
map<int, map<int, map<int, int> > > mp;
```

How do I then look through this map to check if a key exists, and then obtain the value for that key?

I tried

```
map<int, map<int, map<int, int> > >::iterator it = mp[1][3].find(4);
x = it->second;
```

However this gives an error. Why is this wrong?

EDIT: I got the error using 3d array of int, not float

Comment: Sure it gives an error. Your map keys are `int` and you are passing [`1.1`]. That's a double you know.

Comment: I fixed that typo just now

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your goal with a `map<int, map<int, map<int, int> > >`?

Comment: You'd have a much better time with `std::map<std::tuple<int,int,int>, int>`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a better structure would be with a class storing your 3d index and using it as a key ?

```
map<index3D, int> mp;
```

Then you can do something like

```
if(mp.count(index3D(ix, iy, iz)) > 0) // do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assuming v1, v2 and v3 are int indices
if(mp.find(v1) != mp.end() &&
   mp[v1].find(v2) != mp[v1].end() &&
   mp[v1][v2].find(v3) != mp[v1][v2].end())
{
  // Key exist
  const int &value = mp[v1][v2][v3];
  ...
}
else
{
  // Key does not exis
  ...
}
```

You can save temporary iterators/reference and use nested loops if it performs better for you.

Another simpler way to achieve same functionality is to use a `std::tuple<int, int, int>` or `std::pair< std::pair<int, int>, int >` as key. Not that both [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) and [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) provide `operator <`.

> What is the problem with `mp[1][3].find(4)`

You can't apply it on `cons` reference. If `mp[1]` or `mp[1][3]` doesn't exist, this code will unnecessary create new maps.

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/qsOI3b)

Comment: and how do I extract the value and assign it to a variable `x`? Just use `x = it->second;`?

Comment: In success part: Use `mp[v1][v2][v3]`.